# include() is not working

Tags: php, include

So basically all of my files have `include('http://website.com/static/header.php')` nav.php, and footer.php.  It worked on my host, but now I'm hosting it myself on Ubuntu.  It's not working at all!  In php.ini `allow_url_include = On`  Can and yes the files are all there, and the cases are proper.

Comment: If you're requesting the URL, your server is going to parse it and just return the html output, not the actual PHP code.

Comment: Why would you host a header and a footer on the live site? Just use local paths.

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: why would you want to parse the files through the server before including them?

Comment: Does `header.php` output anything? I'm guessing if you are doing an URL include that it must have some sort of output.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, and should be avoided. Just host the files locally.

Comment: header.php consists of a random banner generator that's why.

Comment: quicker, safer, more reliable to include from the local file system.

Comment: @dragon I know but header.php has php that randomly selects banner images which needs to be parsed by php.

Comment: so? i don't see the issue? included files are parsed as if the code was written where the include() is placed

Comment: @dragon the problem is I'm not getting any output from the files.

Comment: Is website.com in the example your website or somebody else's?

Comment: @databyss Example of my website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to include a file from a remote server for what you are trying to do. I would go as far as tell you to **not** do it. If you need some random banner as you state in your question just include the local file:

main.php

```
<?php
// some php code...

include('/path/to/file/banner.php');
```

banner.php

```
<?php

$banners = array('banner1.jpg', 'banner2.jpg');

echo '<img src="' . $banners[mt_rand(0, 1)] . '" alt="some banner">';
```

Comment: Oh, PHP is still parsed when it's a local file?

Comment: Sure. Include does nothing more then include the file and if it contains PHP code it will parse it.